# sybase iq explain plan

Tags: sybase, query-tuning

I am working on Sybase IQ 16 performance tuning. Looking for help from experts to tune my queries.

1)Is there a command that will generate plan output.
2)Is there any generic guidelines/steps to be followed to tune the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IQ generates very nice graphical query plans. This requires setting option query_plan to 'on', plus a few other options (search for 'query_plan' in the docs).

In general (and independent of query plans) I'd recommend enabling the index advisor (see option 'index_advisor' in the docs) and following up the recommendations.

From this point onwards, there are no easy answers, since everything "depends". Google for Mark Mumy's IQ sizing document and take it from there.